# android - How to retrieve all the posts in google+ of the user

Tags: android, google-plus

I am newbie to the google+. I successfully run the sample app that was present in the sdk. Now  i want to retrieve all the posts in stream line of the current user(Logged user). is it possible? if yes, How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot [list activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) from the Android client. If you are interested in listing the user's activities, perform this API from a server instead.

Comment: It means, we are retrieving the posts of the user which are public only. is it right? Is any way to retrieve the posts of the user which is shared to few peoples(private) only?

Comment: Only posts that are public can be read from a user's activity stream.

Comment: We are getting the public posts which are posted by the logged user. we are not getting rest of the public posts which are posted by his/her friends. How do we get it?